# TensorFlow - Index of Blank Label as per CTC Loss Layer

Tags: tensorflow, speech-recognition, recurrent-neural-network

I have a confusion in understanding what values the label SparseTensor should have beyond the actual label length. So for an instance, let's say that I have labels A-Z with indices 0-26 and the target labels are:

```
# 'H','E','L','L','O'
targ1=[7,4,11,11,14] 

# 'N','O'
targ2=[13,14]

sparse = [ [7,4,11,11,14],
           [13,14,0,0,0] ]
```

In sparse, the actual transcript of the second batch appears as `NOAAA` although it is just `NO`. So I would like to know how does TensorFlow handle this while computing loss. Wouldn't this let the network learn to output incorrect sequence of characters? Or can I just make the indices of labels range between 1 to 27, rather than from 0 to 26 therefore forcing the network to output classes only between 1-27, yet I cannot convince myself that even this would work perfectly.

Also I think TensorFlow manual for CTC Loss does not mention about the index of blank label is assumed to be `N_Classes - 1`, which I found here: [CTC Loss op](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d42facc3cc9611f0c9722c81551a7404a0bd3f6b/tensorflow/core/kernels/ctc_loss_op.cc#L146). Could someone confirm whether such an assumption is correct?

I request someone to please clarify my doubts. Thanks for your time, and support.

Answer (score 4):

CTC_OPS source claims

> The `inputs` Tensor's innermost dimension size, `num_classes`, represents
>     `num_labels + 1` classes, where num_labels is the number of true labels, and
>     **the largest value `(num_classes - 1)` is reserved for the blank label**.

Answer (score 0):

I recently studied speech recognition, SparseTensor in tensorflow means that it will add `0` in labels matrix, so the `0` means `no-class`, so i think the index of `blank-label` class is `0`, and the `num_classes` is 1-27.